$f(x)=\frac{x\lfloor x\rfloor}{1+x^2}$. Find range.
Find range of the function $f(x)=\frac{x\lfloor x\rfloor}{1+x^2}$.
My Attempt:
I found this problem really weird. On plotting the graph i observed that $f(x)$ is not able to take value between $0.5$ and $0.6$ and for negative values of $x$, $f(x)$ takes values greater than $1$ for some $x$. The minimum value is $0$ but i cannot ascertain the maximum value or the upper bound.

Hint: Near to the right of integer values, the function will look like $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ while near left of integer values, the function will look like $\frac{x(x-1)}{1+x^2}$. Can you think of a way to use this ?

Determine the range of the function over an interval of the form $m \le x < m+1$ where $m$ is an integer
